# Strategy for selenium-webdriver in javascript for testing in different environments

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, e2e-testing

I've been making a functional tests using selenium-webdriver using yadda library. The problem it's that in my different environments the same test suite working different. Example:

On tests, the result it's different based on the environment that I entry.

**Local** *localhost:5000*

```
Open my search site
      ․ when i go to my site: 2169ms
      ․ when i write a text on the search input: 21ms
      ․ when i click the search button: 130ms
      ․ then i get the results page.": 46ms
```

**Staging** *mystaging.domain.com*

```
 Open my search site: 
         StaleElementReferenceError: {"errorMessage":"Element is no longer attached to the DOM","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"2"
```

**Production** *www.domain.com*

```
   Open my search site
      ․ when i go to my site: 2169ms
      ․ when i write a text on the search input: 21ms
      ․ when i click the search button: 130ms
      ․ then i get the results page.": 46ms
```

At this time, only the staging tests are failing, but in other situations when the internet connection it's slow, the tests fails in production but pass in staging. 
The main problem it's that the browser doesn't have the DOM ready for the test and they doesn't find the element required for the test.

My approach for trying to solve this, it's wait that appear the root element of my page like this:

```
return driver.wait(() => driver.isElementPresent(By.css(".my__homepage")), 50000);
```

But this isn't enough for me, because the test suites are still failing randomly.So, my question it's:

**Which could be a best approach for run in different environments the tests suite dealing with the elements that isn't ready on the browser ?**

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your DOM elements not ready. Before you access any elements you should put an implicit wait on them. So in case your response time increases/decreases from environment to environment, it won't break the testing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I'm trying to set a wait but this isn't work. Do you know if exist a way to make 100%sure that my test wait the load of the entire HTML document like a "ready" event or something like that?

Comment: I can show you some example. Are you using C# or Java (or something) for Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I am showing you a simple C# code which I did for my work in IE browser but it can work similarly for other browsers and languages.

```
private static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)); //max driver wait timeout 120 seconds

try
{
    //waiting for document to be ready
    IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    wait.Until(sc => jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

    //waiting for an element.
    //use 'ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable' as in some cases element gets loaded but might not be still ready to be clicked
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("elementID")));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

- Basically I am putting a wait for the document to be ready using JavaScript executor
- Also I am putting an implicit wait for each element that I would access. I am using expected condition as ElementToBeClickable because sometime ElementIsPresent does not mean element can be accessed as per your needs.

Note: Addiotinally you might also have to check for other element properties (like enabled/disabled, etc) depending on your needs.